# Aero drop - shadow on a borderless form?

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli, drop-shadow, createparams

I tried the following code to override the CreateParams.

```
protected: virtual property System::Windows::Forms::CreateParams^ CreateParams
    {
        System::Windows::Forms::CreateParams^ get() override
        {
            System::Windows::Forms::CreateParams^ cp = Form::CreateParams;
            cp->ClassStyle::set(CS_DROPSHADOW);
            return cp;


        }
    }
```

It works fine. But it does not give the desired result.

This is the type of shadow I wanted...

[image: This is the type of Shadow I wanted.]

And this is what I got from the code...

[image: This is what I got from the code.]

I was thinking if there is any way to get that aero style of Drop-Shadows ?

Comment: http://xenon.arcticus.com/why-cs-dropshadow-class-style-and-how-do-you-use-it-dialog-dlgproc

Comment: @TonyTheLion :: Well, that's a completely useless link. It doesn't make any sense for the asked question.

Comment: @sehe :: Stackoverflow did not ask me to aprove your edit and neither it allows me to remove it, Sehe !! Because technically, there was no corrections made by you in the question.

Comment: @HemendraSharma I added the [tag:c++-cli] tag for you :)